# PowerMock and mocking oracle ArrayDescriptor

Tags: java, oracle, testing, mockito, powermock

I have issue with mocking oracles ArrayDescriptor. Here's a code example:
Let say I have method something like this

```
    public void doSomething(){
    //some code here
    ArrayDescriptor arrayDescriptor = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("TEST", connection);
    //some more code
     }
```

How should I mock that arrayDescriptor part?
I tried something like this:

```
PowerMock.mockStatic(ArrayDescriptor.class);
//connection is mocked
ArrayDescriptor arrayDescriptor = Mockito.mock(ArrayDescriptor.class);
//connection is also mocked
Mockito.when(ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("TEST", connection).thenReturn(arrayDescriptor);
```

But that does not work, throws some kind of nullpointerException related to SQLName, I tried to mock SQLName, but didn't help.

Hopefully someone can help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the call to `ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor( ... )` off into a one-line method of its own class (which can be an inner class of the class where you're using it).  Add a field to the class where you're using this call, that has an instance of the new class.  Use either a setter or a special constructor to set this field to a value that's different from the usual one.  Then mock the inner class, and have it return a mock of `ArrayDescriptor`.  So you might get something like this.

```
public class MyClass{

    class ArrayDescriptorFactory{
        makeArrayDescriptor(String name, Connection connection){
            return ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor(name, connection);
        }
    }

    private ArrayDescriptorFactory factory;

    public MyClass(){
        this( new ArrayDescriptorFactory());
    }

    MyClass(ArrayDescriptorFactory factory){
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    public void doSomething(){
        ... do stuff ...
        factory.makeArrayDescriptor( "something", someConnection );
        ... do more stuff ...
    }
}
```

and in the test

```
@Mock private MyClass.ArrayDescriptorFactory mockFactory;
@Mock private ArrayDescriptor mockArrayDescriptor;

...

initMocks( this );
when( mockFactory.makeArrayDescriptor( anyString(), any( Connection.class )))
.thenReturn( mockArrayDescriptor );
MyClass toTest = new MyClass( mockFactory );
```